# Distance between parallel vectors

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors

Compute the distance between the parallel lines given by
$\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix} + t \begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}$
and
$\begin{pmatrix} -5 \\ 6 \end{pmatrix} + s \begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}.$

I have tried to express these vectors as if they were regular line equations, but with no avail.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can try to find the distance from $(-5,6)$ to the first line, which is given by $x=1+4t, y=4+3t$.

Comment: Do you know how to find a vector normal to those lines?

Answer (score 0):

Since the lines are parallel we need only find the distance from a point $\vec p$ on the first line to the closest point on the second line to $\vec p$. The first line contains the point $\vec p=(1,4)$ so it sufffices to minimize the function
\begin{align*}
D(t)
&= \bigl(1-(-5+4\,t)\bigr)^2+\bigl(4-(6+3\,t)\bigr)^2 \\
&= 25\,t^2-36\,t+40
\end{align*}
(do you see why?). To do this note that
\begin{align*}
D^\prime(t) &= 50\,t-36 \\
D^{\prime\prime}(t) &= 50
\end{align*}
Thus the only critical point of $D(t)$ is $t=36/50$ and this critical point gives a global minimum since $D^{\prime\prime}>0$. Hence the minimum distance from the first line to the second line is
$$
\sqrt{D\left(\frac{36}{50}\right)}=\frac{26}{5}
$$